# Find all results with regular expressions in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Hello I am studying Ruby regular expressions and there is something I can not do, I have a website called http: //localhost/test.php that returns the following:

```
HI WORLD 1 OK
HI WORLD 2 OK
HI WORLD 3 OK
HI WORLD 4 OK
HI WORLD 5 OK
HI WORLD 6 OK
```

The code I'm using is this

```
require "open-uri"
require "net/http"  

def toma(web)
    begin
        return open(web, "User-Agent" => "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0").read
    rescue
        return "Error"
    end
end

code = toma("http://localhost/test.php")

if code=~/WORLD (.*) OK/
    test = $1
    print test+"\n"
end
```

What happens is that only includes the first parameter, I'm looking to find them all, but when I change the if by while the script is labeled and always shows the same in an infinite loop.

The idea is to return something like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Source Updated :

```
lines = code.scan(/WORLD (.*) (.*) OK/)

lines.flatten.each do |line|
    begin
        print line[1]+"\n"
    end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "source updated"? did it solve your problem? did it create another problem? by changing the question, you might void some of the answers. If one of the answers solved your problem - choose it as the correct answer (click the "V" sign next to it); if you have a different problem, consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're new to Ruby, spend time familiarizing yourself with the various methods available on the core classes like String. There's a lot of really handy tools in there.

For example, [`String#scan`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-scan) does a great job here:

```
code.scan(/WORLD (.*) OK/)
# => [["1"],["2"],...]
```

You can convert that to a regular array with `flatten`.

Comment: how read all this list ? , i try with "lineas.each do |linea|" but not work.

Comment: I'm not sure how you assigned `lineas`, but if it's an array then that should work.

Comment: is the result of your source.

Comment: If you iterate directly over those, they'll be arrays, so you'll need to extract the values or do `lines.flatten.each` instead.

Comment: sorry , one last question , if I have one second ( . *) in the regular expression, as I read the value of the second ( . *) to flatten

Comment: If you have two captures, then you'll get two elements in each array. When iterating you can break these out or just skip the `flatten` step and reference them individually as `line[0]` and `line[1]`.

Comment: Source Updated in the post , apply what you said but gives this error "lock in < main> ' : undefined method` + ' for nil : NilClass ( NoMethodError ) "

Comment: It's possible you're missing a match on that line. Whenever practical, have a look at the result of `line.inspect`. `"#{line[0]}\n"` is safer since it will cast to string regardless of what it's given.

Answer (score 0):

If your data truly looks like that, you don't need a regex:

```
str =<<THE_VERY_END
HI WORLD 1 OK
HI WORLD 2 OK
HI WORLD 3 OK
HI WORLD 4 OK
HI WORLD 5 OK
HI WORLD 6 OK
THE_VERY_END
  #=>=> "HI WORLD 1 OK\nHI WORLD 2 OK\nHI WORLD 3 OK\nHI WORLD 4 OK\nHI WORLD 5 OK\nHI WORLD 6 OK\n"

str.lines.map(&:split).transpose[2]
  #=> ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]
```

If you want integers, tack `.map(&:to_i)` to the end.